# Understanding Android Architecture Components example GithubBrowserSample: ViewModelModule, ViewModel parameters

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, dagger, android-viewmodel

One of the most up to date samples covering Android Architecture Components is [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) provided by Google. I reviewed the code and a few questions arose:

1. I have noticed that [ViewModelModule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.kt) is included in [AppModule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppModule.kt). It means that all the viewmodels are added to the DI graph. Why that is done in that way instead of having separate `Module` for each Activity/Fragment that would provide only needed `ViewModel` for specific Activity/Fragment?
2. In this specific example, where viewmodels are instantiated using [GithubViewModelFactory](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.kt) is there any way to pass a parameter to the specific `ViewModel`? Or the better solution would be to create a setter in `ViewModel` and set needed param via setter?

Comment: Someone already created this request: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/148

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. [...] It means that all the viewmodels are added to the DI graph. Why that is done in that way instead of having separate  Module for each Activity/Fragment [...]?

They are added to the DI graph, but they are not yet created. Instead they end up in a map of providers, as [seen in the ViewModelFacory](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/b411aa3f423744ec9b7f4c0559e3938ab2c40547/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.kt#L28).

```
@Inject
public GithubViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) { }
```

So we now have a `GithubViewModelFactory` that has a list of providers and can create any `ViewModel` that was bound. Fragments and Activities can now just inject the factory and retrieve their ViewModel.

```
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

// ...later...
repoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(RepoViewModel.class);
```

As to the why...alternatively you could create a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` for every Activity / Fragment and register the implementation in every Module. This would be a lot of duplicated boilerplate code, though.

> 2. In this specific example, where viewmodels are instantiated using GithubViewModelFactory is there any way to pass a parameter to the specific ViewModel? Or the better solution would be to create a setter in ViewModel and set needed param via setter?

It seems like all the ViewModels only depend on `@Singleton` objects—which is necessary, since they all get provided from the AppComponent. This means that there is no way to pass in "parameters" other than other `@Singleton` dependencies.

So, as you suggested, you'd either have to move the factory down into the Activity / Fragment component so that you can provide lower-scoped dependencies, or use a setter method.

Comment: With earlier dagger2 version (without dagger.android) I used subcomponents. In so in  activity I could do         App.get(context).appComponent.plus(MyModule("12345")).inject(this). So in this module I could instantiate factory with param ViewModelProvider.Factor("12345") that could create me ViewModel with param. How I can do the same using dagger.android injection?

Comment: I have found this approach https://github.com/Nimrodda/dagger-androidinjector/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/codepond/daggersample/feature/FeatureModule.java#L32 Maybe that is the way

Comment: @VadimsSavjolovs keep in mind that the android parts are still in `@Beta`. Currently there is no support for non-default-constructor modules, so the link you posted seems like a possible approach

Comment: > As to the why...alternatively you could create a ViewModelProvider.Factory for every Activity / Fragment and register the implementation in every Module.

Actually that what i do, you may got pb with your DI graph otherwise,  for example providing a per fragment injection in your viewmodel may leading to dagger error "inject need a @provides annotation..."